# JavaScript - understand methods

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I have doubts about understanding the principles of methods.
I understand functions and I know that

```
function hello() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

is the same as

```
var hello = function() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

Now, what's my problem is.
Here is my object with one method. I don't understand why 
parenthesis are don't needed at `yarsLeft` inside `function people()`
I am looking for a logical explanation.

```
function people(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft; // this is confised for me
}

function yearsLeft() {
    var numYears = 65 - this.age;
    return numYears;
}
```

Create object

```
var test = new people('Superman', 50);
test.yearsUntilRetire(); // I understand this code and calling a method in that way
```

Why I can't write `this.yearsUntilRetire() = yearsLeft` or `this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft();`

Comment: It's a function reference. Functions can be referred and passed as any other types in JS.

Comment: `()` will invoke(call) the function. You are setting the function expression to `this.yearsUntilRetire`. Once you call `this.yearsUntilRetire()`, function expression will be executed..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the name of a function without parentheses ( `()`) you are setting a reference to the *function itself*.

When you use the same function with parentheses you are *executing the function*.

Therefore this line

```
this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;
```

Is setting `yearsUntilRetire` to point to the function. Thereafter you can do this:

```
this.yearsUntilRetire(); // execute the yearsLeft function.
```

---

> Why I can't write this.yearsUntilRetire() = yearsLeft or this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft();

In the first case, you cannot set the result of calling a function to a different result - it is a syntax error.

In the second case, you can - it sets the variable `yearsUntilRetire` to the result of calling the function `yearsLeft`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `function hello() {alert('Hello World');}`
**is NOT same as** `var hello = function() {alert('Hello World');}`

First one is a Function declaration. and second one is a Function Expression assigned to a variable called `hello` . but of course  while using these two function, you can think of it as same and both behaves the same.

**2)** function will always be called like Function name followed by parenthesis eg: `yearsLeft()`  . and thats the only way to call a function.

Functions are First Class objects in JS.  It can be declared, Expressed, assigned, pass to another function and returned from a function.

so in your case, your intention is to assign the global function `yearsLeft` to object property `yearsUntilRetire` . which you do exactly the way any other assignment is done -  remember "**Functions are First Class objects**"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of working examples to illustrate the answers to your question.
See comments inline for an explanation.

```js
console.assert( typeof helloWorldAsVar === 'function', 'helloWorldAsVar is defined' );
console.log( helloWorldAsVar );
console.assert( typeof helloWorld === 'function', 'helloWorld is defined' );
// creating a function like helloWorld means it will be hoisted to the top of the file as js does two passes
// when compiling the script. one to declare all the functions and initialize all the variables as undefined.
// and another to run through the code.
console.log(helloWorld);


var helloWorldAsVar = function() {
  return 'this will not get hoisted, and the function name is anonymous';
}
// helloWorldAsVar is only available after it is declared.
console.assert(typeof helloWorldAsVar === 'function', 'helloWorldAsVar is defined');
console.log( helloWorldAsVar );

function helloWorld() {
  return 'this will get hoisted to the top of the function, and it will keep its name';
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js">
</script>
```

```js
// this is a constructor function, it is essentially a typed object that can
// have it's own methods similar to an oop class in other languages like php or java
// the convention is to name a constructor with the first letter capitalized and it should be singular
function Person(name, age) {
  // here you are assigning properties to your People object
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  // you are passing a reference to the yearsLeft function
  // this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;
}

// a more standard way to add the yearsLeft function is to 
// use the People.prototype object which get's methods delegated to it eg.
Person.prototype.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;

function yearsLeft() {
  var numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
}

// Create objects
var superman = new Person('Clark', 50 ),
    batman = new Person('Bruice', 40 );

console.log( superman, 'yearsUntilRetire', superman.yearsUntilRetire() );
console.log( batman, 'yearsUntilRetire', batman.yearsUntilRetire() );

// Why I can 't write this.yearsUntilRetire() = yearsLeft or this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft();
console.assert(this === window, 'this in the global context refers to the window object' );
console.assert(superman instanceof Person, 'superman is a Person' );
console.assert(batman instanceof Person, 'batman is a Person' );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```